# XML tags with same name - Javascript

Tags: javascript, xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<catalogo>

    <item gruppo="Guardoli">
        <pic>img/catalogue/guardoli/G000001.jpg</pic>
        <code>G000001</code>
        <price>0.15cents al metro</price>
        <name>dummy</name>
        <subcat>Leather</subcat>
        <color>red</color>
        <color>green</color>
        <color>yellow</color>
        <color>blue</color>
    </item>
</catalogue>
```

As found above, you will see that I presented you with an XML piece of code that I am using for a personal database. The search in the xml happens with Javascript and I already have a function that does what it has to do.

My question is the following: I would like to add a search option (with checkboxes) that makes you choose the available colors the "item" should have to be found by the search.

In example: I want to find all items that are part of the "gruppo = Guardoli", "subcategory = leather" and along with that all those products I want to find shall be produced both in red and yellow colors.

The final question : Is it possible to use the tag "color" more than one time, just like I did in the example? The fastest way for me would be to duplicate the item and give it each time a different color tag but it seems to me to be a bad form.

Can you help me? :)

Comment: We can't possibly help you unless you show the JavaScript code.

Comment: I asked if I can use two or more times the same xml tag name, why would you even need to check the javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is in response to your last question about using the color element more than once.

There's nothing wrong with using the same element multiple times.  In fact, it's accommodated by XML schema occurrence indicators.  For example, you can set `maxOccurs` and/or `minOccurs` to limit the range of occurrences allowed.

If you'd like to validate the XML this way,  you'll need to create a schema and use a validating XML parser in your code.

Checkout the example, MyFamily.xml and family.xsd on this [schema tutorial page](http://www.w3schools.com/Schema/schema_complex_indicators.asp).